# Fluent mapping help

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent

This is probably a very simple question but I'm new to nHibernate and I'm having trouble working this out.

I have a Page object, which can have many Region objects. I also have a Workflow object. Page and Region objects both have a relationship to Workflow and it's this double association that I'm having trouble with.

The PageMap has

```
HasMany(Function(x) x.Regions).Cascade.All()
```

And the RegionMap has:

```
 References(Function(x) x.Page)
```

And this all seems to work.

But how do I define the relationship between Workflow and these two objects?

Comment: Consider posting a diagram of your data model to make it less work for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

How is it in your database? If both have a foreign key to workflow, then both get a `Workflow` property mapped as:

```
References(Function(x) x.Workflow)
```

in each mapping class. If only the `Page` has it, and the `Region`'s is therefore inferred, add an unmapped readonly property on `Region` thus:

```
public Workflow Workflow { get { return Page.Workflow; } }
```

Comment: Hi. Both have a foreign key. But how do I map the inverse relationship? I thought you had to use a HasMany() on the other side of a relationship from References()?

I'm also slightly confused as to where best to use Inverse and Cascade ...